# jquery datatable - Get column name by clicking on table footer cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to get the column name when the user clicks on the jquery datatable's footer cell.

I tried to follow this: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24593/retreive-column-idx-when-clicking-on-header

And, https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector

But, I am getting 'undefined' with the following code,

```
    $('#myTable').on( 'click', 'tfoot th', function () {
        var index = table.column( this ).index(); //index is returned as undefined
   } );
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not just `$(this).index()` (no clue how datatables works)

Comment: did you try with `$(this)`instead of only using `this` ? I am not sure, but if I remember correctly, that has been the source of the issue for me before

Comment: @epascarello, let me try your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Columns can be selected only if you use header `th` nodes or table body `td` nodes, that's why it doesn't work.

#### SOLUTION

Try the code below to get actual column index.

Modifier [`:visible`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) is needed because `$(this).index()` operates with actual DOM elements and returns index of the `th` node among currently visible columns. However jQuery DataTables may remove columns from DOM when using various extensions, such as [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/), [Buttons - Column visibility](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html), etc, and actual column index may differ from index of the column in DOM.

```
$('#example').on( 'click', 'tfoot th', function () { 
    var index = table.column($(this).index() + ':visible').index();
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/3z45bnz6/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks. using the above code, im able get the column name as well, let columnName = table.column(index).dataSrc();

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh, no need to use `column()` method twice. Just use `var col = table.column($(this).index() + ':visible');` and then you can use `col.dataSrc()`.